# need to call ssl::stream::shutdown when closing boost asio ssl socket?

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, ssl, boost-asio

My code is as follows:

```
declaration: boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> m_remote_socket;

m_remote_socket.shutdown(ec);
if (ec)
{      
    cdbug<<"id: "<<m_id<<", error when ssl shutdown: "    <<boost::system::system_category().message(ec.value()).c_str(); 
}
m_remote_socket.lowest_layer().shutdown(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_both, ec);
if (ec)
{
    cdbug<<"id: "<<m_id<<", error when tcp shutdown: "<<boost::system::system_category().message(ec.value()).c_str(); 
}
```

Each time I call `m_remote_socket.shutdown`, it will get an error. Such kind of unknown error with a really big error value.

But it is ok to call `m_remote_socket.lowest_layer().shutdown()` directly without calling `m_remote_socket.shutdown`.

Could anybody tell me how to close a ssl streaming socket?

Comment: What is the error code and message when shutdown fails?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is cleanest to make `shutdown()` calls on both the `ssl::stream` and its `lowest_layer()`.  The first [ends the SSL connection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Alert_protocol) and the second [ends the TCP connection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Connection_termination).  If you're getting an error on the SSL shutdown, it may be that the other side is not being as graceful in ending the connection.

Comment: That's not correct. It isn't legal for the TCP connection underlying an SSL connection to be half-closed. See RFC 2246.

Comment: @EJP, I'm not sure I understand what you mean.  The fact that SSL connections should be closed before the lower protocol layers doesn't prevent the side you're communicating with from closing or dropping TCP.  I'm just trying to explain why you may get an error when trying to shut down SSL.

Comment: @rashimodo There is no such thing as a half-closed SSL connection. Once one side receives a close_notify, it must close the connection. I'm surprised the library under discussion even provides an SSL shutdown, but if it does and it works the result must be a completely closed connection. Shutting down one side of the underlying TCP connection leaves SSL in an invalid state. This answer is not correct.

Comment: Thanks, Finally i know why it has the error: there is still unfinished io operation pending on this

Comment: socket. and the error disappear after i move the close operation to the destructor

Answer (score 3):

I do highly recommend that you should not use shutdown method and don't respect SSL layer + TCP layer (lowest_layer). be in safe side and close the tcp lowest_layer as

m_remote_socket.lowest_layer().close(ec);

The problem i faced that the time you respect the SSL or TCP, the application resources(socket handler) will stock in memory till server side send close session ack.

Answer (score 1):

Just call close(). It isn't legal to shutdown SSL sockets: there is no such thing as a half-close in SSL. See RFC 2246, discussion of close_notify.

Comment: What is your definition of "shutdown"?  I think one of us has a semantic misunderstanding.  The [OpenSSL concept of shutdown](http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_shutdown.html) is sending `close_notify`, and this is what `boost::asio` invokes.

Comment: The TCP notion of shutdown is a half close: sending a FIN in one direction while keeping the other direction open. This is what 'shutdown(SHUT_WR)' does. The SSL notion of close_notify is a full close. 'The currently open session is considered closed'. They are not reconcilable.

Comment: That's why my answer says to call `shutdown()` on the `ssl::stream`.  That does **not** send FIN and end the TCP connection; it calls OpenSSL `SSL_shutdown` which sends `close_notify`.  `ssl::stream::shutdown()` == `close_notfify`.  `SSL_shutdown()` != TCP FIN.

Comment: Quite, so you should not *also* do the TCP shutdown. I would also observe that if this shutdown method doesn't do a half close, it is badly misnamed.

Comment: We now agree calling `ssl::stream::shutdown()` (which sends `close_notify`) is correct, yes? After this are you going to leave the TCP connection idle forever? The connection should be ended cleanly with FIN, and TLS section 7.2.1 explicitly permits immediate TCP shutdown after sending `close_notify`. As for the naming of "shutdown", this is the term used by both [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_shutdown.html) and [NSS](http://mxr.mozilla.org/nss/source/lib/ssl/sslsecur.c#1069) for alerting `close_notify` **without** closing the TCP transport.

Comment: @rhashimoto My answer clearly says 'just call `close()`. This is not the same thing as 'leav[ing] the TCP connection idle forever'. Your point eludes me.

Comment: Your comment above says "you should not also do the TCP shutdown" and "if this shutdown method doesn't do a half close, it is badly misnamed". This implied to me that you are saying that if you call `shutdown()` at the SSL layer then you do not need to call `close()` at the TCP layer. If you want to go back to your answer, only calling `close()` is incorrect. `close()` is a method on `boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket()` and does nothing at the SSL/TLS layer.

Comment: @rhashimoto You cannot by any convolution of logic derive 'you do not need to call `close()`' from an answer that says `just call `close()`'. If `boost::asio`'s SSL close is called shutdown it is badly misdesigned.

Comment: It looks like you're ignoring the context of my comment, which begins with referencing your comment where you say, "you should not also do the TCP shutdown", which contradicts your original answer. It looks like your issue is with the boost::asio API design. Perhaps you are also unfamiliar with the OpenSSL API, as the shutdown concept is identical there (as my very first comment points out). Even if you don't like the API, your answer does not send close_notify.