# What is the correct way to close boost::asio::ssl::stream

Tags: c++, sockets, ssl, boost, boost-asio

I am using `boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket>` as a server-side SSL-Socket. Sometimes, I need to close the connection to the client. In the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15312219/need-to-call-sslstreamshutdown-when-closing-boost-asio-ssl-socket) it says:

> It is cleanest to make `shutdown()` calls on both the `ssl::stream` and
>   its `lowest_layer()`. The first ends the SSL connection and the second
>   ends the TCP connection.

I turned that into code:

```
this->_sslSocket.shutdown();
this->_sslSocket.lowest_layer().shutdown(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_both, shutdown_error);
this->_sslSocket.lowest_layer().close();
```

However, one of the calls is always producing an error: "shutdown: End of file". I am sure that the client is not the problem, because I am using [OpenSSL's s_client](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:S_client(1)) to debug the application, and the error still occurs.

Why is this happening and how can I avoid it?

Comment: Take a look at: [what is the proper way to securely disconnect an asio ssl socket](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32046034/what-is-the-proper-way-to-securely-disconnect-an-asio-ssl-socket)